# First-order equation: $y'=(x+y)/(y-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\frac{x+y}{y-x}$$
$${y=tx,\ t=\frac{y}{x} }$$
$$t'x+t=\frac{1+\frac{y}{x}}{\frac{y}{x}-1}$$
...few steps later...
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 - 2\frac{y}{x}-1}=\frac{1}{Cx},\ C=\text{const}$$
That's ugly. Teacher told me that the answer should look more clean. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could square both sides and clear the $x^2$ from the denominator to get
$$y^2 - 2xy - x^2 = C$$
(my $C$ is different from your $C$).

In this form, it is easy to see the correctness of your solution. 
Applying $d$ to both sides yields
$$2y~dy - 2x~dy - 2y~dx - 2x~dx = 0$$
$$(2y-2x)~dy = (2y+2x)~dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y+2x}{2y-2x} = \frac{y+x}{y-x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(x)=\frac{y(x)+x}{y(x)-x}\Leftrightarrow y'(x)y(x)-xy'(x)-y(x)=x\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(y^2(x))'-(xy(x))'=x$$
direct integration of both sides yields
$$\frac{1}{2}\int(y^2(x))'\,dx-\int(xy(x))'\,dx=\int x\,dx\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}y^2(x)-xy(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+C$$
in other words
$$y^2(x)-2xy(x)-x^2=C$$
So using quadratic formula
$$y(x)=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4x^2+4x^2+4C}}{2}=x\pm\sqrt{2x^2+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

this seems a little special so you can do this $$ {dy \over dx} = {x + y \over y-x} $$ can be turned into $$0 = ydy -(xdy+ydx) - xdx = d\left(\frac{1}{2}y^2 - xy -\frac{1}{2}x^2 \right) =\frac{1}{2}d\ [(x-y)^2 - 2x^2]$$

therefore, $$y = x \pm \sqrt{2(C + x^2)} \mbox{ where $C$  is anyy constant. }$$